# FLASH WRAPPER (INSTALLATION WRAPPER)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2

Could anyone suggest the best methods and software for wrapping my swf so it can install on a mac and PC?

I'm wanting to distribute flash project to run from the desktop with all the icons and bells and whistles etc.

Thanks for your help.

Regards

J

Comment: Why not make it AIR project? It's flash for desktop and have everything you need...

Comment: Hello George, thanks for that. I've tinkered with air briefly but does it allow for you to embed icon and desktop short cuts into task bars?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly do you mean, but yeah, it has all the properties that you would use for a desktop application. Look for an .xml file,(maybe application.xml) in your project, and change what you need. Just google it, you'll find what u are looking for...

Comment: That sounds quite complicated, but I will have a play with it some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If AIR is missing something you need, there are other wrappers out there.  I've used Zinc (http://www.multidmedia.com) with good results (although not for a while-- AIR suits most needs these days).  Zinc allows you to build your own extensions.

Comment: Hello, thanks! I have been playing with Zinc. looks to have a lot of promise? Does it offer a full screen option so that it blocks out all of the icons and task bar etc, I know you can declare this in flash but I wasn't sure in about Zinc!

Comment: I'm not sure offhand, but you can check the Zinc LiveDocs at http://www.multidmedia.com/support/livedocs/zinc/4.0/

Comment: Thanks again, I will have a look.